# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' while object creation of a Model

Tags: tuples, attributeerror

While Defining a model happyModel()

Implements the forward propagation for the binary classification model:
ZEROPAD2D -> CONV2D -> BATCHNORM -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> DENSE

Note that for simplicity and grading purposes, you'll hard-code all the values
such as the stride and kernel (filter) sizes.
Normally, functions should take these values as function parameters.

model -- TF Keras model (object containing the information for the entire training process)

```
def happyModel():
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        ## ZeroPadding2D with padding 3, input shape of 64 x 64 x 3
    tfl.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3,3), data_format=(64,64,3)),
        
        ## Conv2D with 32 7x7 filters and stride of 1
    tfl.Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv0'),
        
        ## BatchNormalization for axis 3
    tfl.BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn0'),
        
        ## ReLU
    tfl.Activation('relu'),
        
        ## Max Pooling 2D with default parameters
    tfl.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool0'),
        
        ## Flatten layer
    tfl.Flatten(),
        
        ## Dense layer with 1 unit for output & 'sigmoid' activation
    tfl.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc'),
        
        # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
        
        # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    ]
)

return model
```

Object Creation of the defined model:

```
      happy_model = happyModel()
      # Print a summary for each layer
      for layer in summary(happy_model):
           print(layer)

      output = [['ZeroPadding2D', (None, 70, 70, 3), 0, ((3, 3), (3, 3))],
                 ['Conv2D', (None, 64, 64, 32), 4736, 'valid', 'linear', 'GlorotUniform'],
                 ['BatchNormalization', (None, 64, 64, 32), 128],
                 ['ReLU', (None, 64, 64, 32), 0],
                 ['MaxPooling2D', (None, 32, 32, 32), 0, (2, 2), (2, 2), 'valid'],
                 ['Flatten', (None, 32768), 0],
                 ['Dense', (None, 1), 32769, 'sigmoid']]

      comparator(summary(happy_model), output)
```

The error I am getting "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'"

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-f33284fd82fe> in <module>
----> 1 happy_model = happyModel()
  2 # Print a summary for each layer
  3 for layer in summary(happy_model):
  4     print(layer)
  5 

 <ipython-input-49-b5fc98b1ebba> in happyModel()
 21 
 22             ## ZeroPadding2D with padding 3, input shape of 64 x 64 x 3
 ---> 23         tfl.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3,3), data_format=(64,64,3)),
 24 
 25             ## Conv2D with 32 7x7 filters and stride of 1

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py in 
   __init__(self, padding, data_format, **kwargs)
  2800   def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), data_format=None, **kwargs):
  2801     super(ZeroPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  -> 2802     self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
  2803     if isinstance(padding, int):
  2804       self.padding = ((padding, padding), (padding, padding))

  /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in 
  normalize_data_format(value)
  190   if value is None:
  191     value = backend.image_data_format()
  --> 192   data_format = value.lower()
  193   if data_format not in {'channels_first', 'channels_last'}:
  194     raise ValueError('The `data_format` argument must be one of '

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What is the reason behind it? Can anyone suggest me any solutions! TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was in the parameter of the function definition. The following code works for me and solves the problem.

```
def happyModel():

Implements the forward propagation for the binary classification model:
ZEROPAD2D -> CONV2D -> BATCHNORM -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> DENSE   
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
        ## ZeroPadding2D with padding 3, input shape of 64 x 64 x 3
    tfl.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3,3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), data_format=None),
        
        ## Conv2D with 32 7x7 filters and stride of 1
    tfl.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=7, strides=1,padding='valid'),
        
        ## BatchNormalization for axis 3
     
    tfl.BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn0'),    
        ## ReLU
    tfl.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0, threshold=0),
        
        ## Max Pooling 2D with default parameters
    tfl.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid',data_format=None),
        
        ## Flatten layer
    tfl.Flatten(data_format=None),
        
        ## Dense layer with 1 unit for output & 'sigmoid' activation
    tfl.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc'),    
        
    ])

return model
```